# consumir un servicio asp.net e importar datos a una tabla sql

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net

Tengo un servicio el cual al ingresar un numero de una factura  me trae unos campos y la informacion , lo que necesito realizar es insertar esos mismos campos con la informacion a una tabla sql

estoy es lo que tengo, el momento solo me trae los datos, pero no se como importarlos a sql

```
webserverDespacho.IntercambioSW service = new webserverDespacho.IntercambioSW();
        DataTable dDataTable = service.aviso_despacho(TxtFactura.Text);
        DataRow[] currentRows = dDataTable.Select(
        null, null, DataViewRowState.CurrentRows);
        if (currentRows.Length < 1)
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write("No Current Rows Found");
        else
        {
            foreach (DataColumn column in dDataTable.Columns)
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write("\t{0}", column.ColumnName);
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("\tRowState");
            foreach (DataRow row in currentRows)
            {
                foreach (DataColumn column in dDataTable.Columns)
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write("\t{0}","" + row[column]);
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("\t" + row.RowState);
            }
        }
```

de esta forma estoy intentando guardar los datos en la table de sql

```
 string strCon = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Sk_DBRadioFrecuencias"].ConnectionString;
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(strCon);
    SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand();
    comm.Connection = conn;
    for (int i = 0; dDataTable.Rows.Count > i; i++)
    {
        //insert Query
        comm =  "insert into  SE_FactEmbarque (SE_Factura, SE_Almacen_Despacho, SE_Orden_De_Venta) values ('" + dDataTable.Rows[i]["factura"].ToString().Trim() + "','" +
            dDataTable.Rows[i]["almacen_despacho"].ToString().Trim() + "','" + dDataTable.Rows[i]["ov"].ToString().Trim()+ "')";
    }
```

Pero me esta saliendo un error.

y esta es la informacion que me trae el servicio

```
<factura diffgr:id="factura1" msdata:rowOrder="0" diffgr:hasChanges="inserted">
<factura>CD-00007</factura>
<almacen_despacho>CDIS</almacen_despacho>
<ov>OV238619</ov>
<oc>57-5776159</oc>
<fechaov>201503101130</fechaov>
<vendido_a>HOMCE33</vendido_a>
<ean_vendido_a>7703670900573</ean_vendido_a>
<cobrar_a>HOMCE33</cobrar_a>
<ean_cobrar_a>7703670900573</ean_cobrar_a>
<despachar_a>HOMCE33</despachar_a>
<ean_despachar_a>7703670900573</ean_despachar_a>
<nombre_despachar_a>HC Santa Marta</nombre_despachar_a>
<articulo>204804</articulo>
<descripcion>Lav S 55x43cm Grafado</descripcion>
<ean_articulo>7707021248048</ean_articulo>
<cantidad_facturada>6</cantidad_facturada>
<cantidad_pendiente>6</cantidad_pendiente>
<peso>2,2</peso>
<volumen>0,003</volumen>
</factura>
```

Comment: Por favor, reformula la pregunta. Estas preguntando cómo insertar datos desde asp.net en SQL-Server o, cómo enviar datatos mediante un servicio web para que se inserten el la base de datos asociada a ese servicio web?

Comment: El servicio web lo realizo un externo, lo que necesito es guardar esa informacion que me llega en una table de sql

Comment: Agrega la estructura de la tabla destino; Si ya existe muestra cómo es, si aún no existe, muestra cómo quieres que sea. Y adiciona los datos del ejemplo como resultado esperado.

Comment: mire como estoy realizando el insert, o no se si exista una mejor forma de hacerlo.

Comment: cual es el error?

Comment: No me esta insertando en la base de datos y dice Error 36 Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand'

Comment: El problema es que estas asignando el texto de la consulta directamente al objeto del SqlCommand, cuando deberías asignarselo a su propiedad .CommandText. Lo mejor será que revises la documentación adecuada de este objeto: https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aconsejaria utilices simpre parametros cuando armas una query, NUNCA concatenes en un string los valores, es una mala practica.

Algo como esto

```
string strCon = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Sk_DBRadioFrecuencias"].ConnectionString;
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(strCon);
conn.Open();

string query =  @"insert into SE_FactEmbarque (SE_Factura, SE_Almacen_Despacho, SE_Orden_De_Venta) 
                    values (@factura, @alamacen,  @ordenventa)";

SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand(query, conn);

foreach (var row in dDataTable.Rows)
{
    comm.Parameters.Clear();
    comm.Parameters.AddWitValue("@factura", row["factura"].ToString().Trim());
    comm.Parameters.AddWitValue("@alamacen", row["almacen_despacho"].ToString().Trim());
    comm.Parameters.AddWitValue("@ordenventa", row["ov"].ToString().Trim());

    comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

como veras el codigo queda ams ordenado y legible